# Remove The Percentage From Google Pie Chart Tooltip

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, google-visualization

How To Remove The Percentage From Google Charts Tooltip

For Example i want remove 33.33% from this tooltip only show the value [image: i want remove 33.33% from this tooltip only show the value]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set `tooltip.text` to `value`. See gogle docs [pie chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart). For example:

```
    var options = {
        'title':  'Pie chart title',
        'width':  800,
        'height': 600,
        'is3D':   false,
        tooltip: {
            text: 'value'
        }
    };
```

Comment: hi i want to change the % colour http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21459382/change-the-google-pie-chart-percentage-text-colour