# Change the Google pie Chart percentage text Colour

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-visualization

How to change the pie chart Percentage colour 
I want To change the 33.33% in black colour
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change it using option `pieSliceTextStyle`. For example:

```
        pieSliceTextStyle: {
            color: 'black'
        }
```

**Note:** that will change font color for all slices. See [pie chart configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#Configuration_Options).

You can use also option `slices` with property `textStyle` to set color for each slice differently: *textStyle - Overrides the global pieSliceTextSlice for this slice.*

Comment: Hi i used legendtype:labeled but in that they showing percentage instead of value http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21472845/google-pie-chart-legend-type-labeled-showing-percentage