# Google Pie Chart Legend type Labeled Showing Percentage

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-visualization

How to Show The value instead of percentage Legend Type Labeled google pie chart i want show percentage in below completed instead of 100% have to show  1

```
 legend: {
 position: 'labeled',
 pieSliceText:"value"                                    
 },
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`legend` option has no property `pieSliceText`. `pieSliceText` is option of whole pie chart. It seems that there is no option to turn off % in legend but you can turn off legend completely using:

```
      legend: {
          position: 'none'
      }
```

and build your own. How it is done is described in answer of [How to add Percentage and Total on the Legend of Google Pie Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089794/how-to-add-percentage-and-total-on-the-legend-of-google-pie-charts). You can show your own text with additional information and styling.

Comment: Hi anto Thank You For Sugession

Comment: Hi anto PiesliceText showing Outside of the pieslices like percentage or value are displaying outside the circle.

Comment: Hi How to show Percentage in Center of the slices http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544867/percentage-in-slices-showing-outside-of-the-ring-slices