# Percentage in Slices Showing Outside OF the Ring Slices

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-visualization

Google Pie Chart Percentage Is showing Outside The Slices.,i wnat to show percentage like red colour slice

[image]

Comment: And what is the exact problem with what you tried?

Comment: @Pierre : i am having percentage 33.33% in all slices. Yellow and Blue Color Slices Percentage Values Are went Outside the slices. I want to make inside to show it like Red Color Slice

Answer (score 1):

You have too small chart size for that font size.

One option is to change property `fontSize`. That one is default font size. It will influence everything.

The other is to change `fontSize` of property `pieSliceTextStyle`. For example:

```
    var options = {
        title: 'Chart Title',
        pieHole: 0.4,
        pieSliceTextStyle: {
            fontSize: 7
        }
    };
```

Choose font size which suits you.

See google docs [about pie chart configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#Configuration_Options)

Comment: To clarify: the text positioning ignores the `pieHole` option, and there is no way to adjust the position of the text, so you can either adjust the size of the pie hole, the size of the chart, or the size of the text to make it fit right.